# Order/List Visio shapes by size in Shape array

Tags: c#, visio

I added the Visio shapes to an Shape Array.
I'm trying to list down the Visio shapes by its size. How do I Order it in Ascending/Decending Order?

```
Shape[] VisioShape = new Shape[0];
int Count = 0
foreach (Shape shape in VisioPage.Shapes)
{
if (shape.OneD != 0)
 { 
   VisioShape[Count] = shape;
   Count++;
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about some LINQ?  The following is a quick snippet I wrote in LinqPad (as per this post: http://visualsignals.typepad.co.uk/vislog/2015/12/getting-started-with-c-in-linqpad-with-visio.html)

```
void Main()
{
    var vApp = MyExtensions.GetRunningVisio();

    Visio.Page vPag = vApp.ActivePage;
    var q = from s in vPag.Shapes.Cast<Visio.Shape>()
            where s.OneD == 0
            orderby s.CellsU["Height"].ResultIU
            select s.Text;
    q.Dump();
}
```

Given some shapes like this:

[image: Visio shapes]

Linqpad returns this:

[image]

If you want to order in the other direction just add `descending` on the end of the orderby line:

```
orderby s.CellsU["Height"].ResultIU descending
```